# combine multiple range vba for each loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops, foreach

so hopefully im doing this correctly. Im learning VBA but really struggling for this one.

The loop shown below works as a seperate entity (eg a loop for "d") but not working correctly when combined below (e.g. loop for "d" and "h")

Basically what im trying to do is to output the values (string) of each cell in a row then once completed then move onto the next row.

But i didnt know how to get each cell to reference to the values "text1" and "text2"

below is my data table in excel

```
Testme = D2
Testme2 = D3
Testme3 = D4
Testme4 = D5

Text2 = H1
wewewe = H2
wewewe2 = H3
wewewe = H4
wewewe3 = H5`




 Dim d As Range
 For Each d In Range(Range("D2"), Range("D2").End(xlDown))
 Dim text1
 text1 = d 'Text1

 Dim h As Range
 For Each h In Range(Range("H2"), Range("H2").End(xlDown))
 Dim text2
 text2 = h 'Text2

Next
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```vb
Sub testme()

Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Dim ws As Workbook: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim rngData As Range, rngCell As Range

With ws
    Set rngData = Union( _
                    .Range("D2:D" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row), _
                    .Range("H2:H" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row) _
                    )
End With

For Each rngCell In rngData
    rngCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = rngCell.Address & " value: " & rngCell.Value
Next rngCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi thank you for helping me.

Im getting text1 and text 2 variable not defined.

I tried to add the following:

```Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim text1, text2
    Dim d, h
    text1 = d
    text2 = h``` text1 and text2 are referenced later down the script and need a string value to be passed

Comment: Is unclear what you are ultimately trying to achieve... I've did my best to provide an answer to your question, but if you feel you need more help, you should edit your question, add more info (i.e.: how your data looks, and how you expect the result to be). Ultimately there are various ways to achieve the same result, some better than others, the above is just a proof of concept on how you can reference cells in a loop, from different ranges... (which is what I understood you've asked). If you add some data to column D and H, test the above and see what it gives you, then tweak to your needs.